# Why is my google chart javascript not doing anything?

Tags: javascript, html, scala, playframework, google-visualization

In my home.scala.html page's *head* I have a comprehensive javascript to call a google chart, using a map passed from scala using the *java play framework*.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'xVariable');
  data.addColumn('number', 'yVariable');

  var mapVariable = @mapFromScala;

  console.log("Hello world");

  for (var mapKey in mapVariable) {
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(mapKey) , mapVariable[mapKey]]
  ]);
  }

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'This is my map',
      subtitle: 'it has a subtitle'
    },
    width: 1000,
    height: 600
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chartId'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}

</script>
```

and in body

```
<div id="chartId"></div>
```

Why don't I get anything back? Even the 'Hello world' `console.log` doesn't seem to show in SBT console.

Comment: Is your Javascript code actually being executed? I.e. if you put a `console.log` at the very top of your script, is that message being logged?

Comment: Yes it appears the javascript isn't being executed, although a console.log at the start of a working google chart (i.e. an example pulled from documentation) doesn't appear in sbt console either.

Comment: The gstatic script was imported and is now included in the question for clarity

Comment: The console.log will not (and is not supposed to) appear in SBT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map variable must be brought in as a String. JSON can be used for this but

```
var mapVariable = "@mapFromScala"
```

Also works, although the process to convert from String back into a Map is inelegant.

This process is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629535/how-do-i-pass-a-java-maplong-integer-into-scala-play), except the data types are different and

```
data.addRows([[xVariable, yVariable]])
```

is invoked instead of

```
jsArray.xVariable = yVariable;
```