# How do I pass a Java Map<Long, Integer> into scala-play?

Tags: javascript, java, scala, playframework

In my play framework project I have a confirmed functional Java map of the form Java that is passed to a html page `home.scala.html`

The map variable is passed in as other (working) variables are, at the top of the page:

```
@(workingVar1: String, workingVar2: Int, mapVar: Map[Long, Integer])
```

But developer tools in google chrome highlights this part of the javascript (embedded in home.scala.html's head):

```
var myMap = @mapVar;
```

With the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =`

So none of the javascript works. What is the correct way to pass this map in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An inelegant but functional solution is as follows:

Bring in the Java Map as a string:

```
  var stringMap = "@mapVar";
```

Removes the braces and spaces inserted into the string unnecessarily

```
  stringMap = stringMap.replace(/{/g,'');
  stringMap = stringMap.replace(/}/g,'');
  stringMap = stringMap.replace(/ /g,'');
```

Split the mapString by `,` and for every pair split again by `=`, extracting keys and values as you go. These will need to be parsed to their correct data-types before adding to a javascript array `jsArr`:

```
  var pairArray = mapString.split(",");
  pairArray.forEach(function(pair) {
      var values = pair.split("=");
      var longString = values[0];
      var intString = values[1];
      var myLong = parseFloat(longString);
      var myInt = parseInt(intString);
      jsArr.myLong = myInt;
}
```

Where jsArr has been defined previously.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java/Scala variables in Twirl Scala templates and both are executed on the server side. 
Now on server side Twirl engine translates Java object to something (which probably isn't what you want) and in this form is passed to client, and then this JavaScript is executed.

You want to make sure that client will receive valid JavaScript code.
To assign proper value, you will have to mix some JSON libraries, which will help you assign value in a proper way.

Eg. on the controller side:

```
...
Map<Long, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1L, 2);
map.put(3L, 3);
String yourMap = Json.stringify(Json.toJson(map));
```

Now you want to pass `yourMap` to view, and then you will assign to `myMap`
using `@Html` as we want it as raw content fragment:

```
@(workingVar1: String, workingVar2: Int, mapVar: String)
var myMap = @Html(mapVar);
```

Try and let me know if it helped.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Doing as you suggest and requesting a console.log(myMap) after assigning it to @Html(mapVar) gave me
[object Object]

Comment: So it is correct, right? Now it is JavaScript object with fields, which were your keys in map and corresponding values.